# ¿Como pasar varios parámetros en un método de una Web API?

Tags: web, xamarin, webapi

quiero realizar una petición POST pasando dos parámetros. He estado leyendo por ahí, que se puede pasar un parámetro por el Body y otro por la URI, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

a ver si me podéis echar un cable, soy principiante en Web API.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: no conozco webAPI, pero si vas a hacer una petición `POST`, todos los parámetros que envíes van en `Body`, por definición del propio verbo. Ademas por lo que he visto de doc asi a primeras, webAPI esta pensado para hacer apis Rest, por lo que deberias cumplir dichas normas (y entre ells tienes el uso de los verbos de http)

Comment: @Jakala He visto algún entorno que al hacer POST también procesa los parámetros que se envían con la URI, aunque tienes razón que no es estándar y que quien confie en esta forma de hacer las cosas se arriesga a que le deje de funcionar el sistema en cualquier cambio o migración.

Comment: Eso es que no cumplen Rest. Otra cosa es que a la gente nos enseñan mal y nos dicen que puedes enviar un formulario por get o post. Una vez empiezas a entender Rest y el uso de los verbos Http te das cuenta que esas cosas estan mal, por la propia definicion. :)

Comment: Hola Jose Manuel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio. Tu pregunta se considera de baja calidad porque no muestras nada de lo intentado. Dices no tener ni idea, lo cual es entendible, pero **es importante** que añadas el trabajo de investigacion y el intento, aunque sea minimo, y por qué no te funcionó o qué es exactamente el problema que has tenido probando. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. De no tener esa información, la pregunta podría cerrarse por ser muy amplia o no claro lo que preguntas. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

**No es recomendable** pasar los parámetros de los POST por URI, aun así se puede hacer:

https://tuWeb/tuPath/tuMetodoPost?param1=25&param2=coco

Mejor usar el body, mírate sobre los tipos de contenido que se puede mandar

```
(Content-Type)
URI: https://tuWeb/tuPath/tuMetodoPost
"Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 27

param1 = 25 & param2 = coco"
```

Puedes mirar https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: Alexis, podrias poner en negrita lo de "No es recomendable" para que quede destacado? es un punto importante, para que la gente vaya `educandose` en este uso de los verbos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos, estoy empezando en esto, y al principio cuesta un poco.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la forma de pasar parametros por medio de POST a un web API.

```
async void PostRequest(string URL)
    {
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("somekey", "1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("somekey2", "2"), 
            });

        var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Events result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json);
    }
```

Esta informacion fue extraida del foro: Xamarin Forums

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64738/post-request-using-httpclient